# UWP RichEditBox InsertImage inserts a blank

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, richeditbox

I'm working on a UWP using Visual Studio Community 2015. I created a blank project, added a button and RichEditBox. I'm trying to insert an image in RichEditBox from local resources, but I only insert a blank placeholder (with the desired size of the image). No errors are thrown.

Here is the code behind:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png");
    using (IRandomAccessStream ras = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(imageUri).OpenReadAsync())
    {
        box.Document.Selection.InsertImage(64, 64, 0, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "img", ras);
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml:

```
<Button Content="Insert image" Click="Button_Click"/>
<RichEditBox Name="box" Height="200"/>
```

Build action of StoreLogo.png is "content", I tried to copy the image to the output directory which made no difference.

What could be the problem here? What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see your issue, however, in my experience, the common way is using [`StorageFile.OpenAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.StorageFile.OpenAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to get `IRandomAccessStream`. And set it to [`ITextRange.InsertImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Text.ITextRange.InsertImage);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).

For example:

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png");

StorageFile imageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(imageUri);

using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))

{

    box.Document.Selection.InsertImage(64, 64, 0, VerticalCharacterAlignment.Baseline, "img", fileStream);

}
```

You can try to use this way to work around it.